# TYPO3 copied/existing installation

Tags: installation, typo3

I'm installing a TYPO3 installation from a website that already uses TYPO3.
These are the steps I already have done:

- I installed a blank TYPO3 installation.
- I copied the contentapi and contentelements from the existing server to the typo3conf/ext folder on my server
- I imported the data from the mysql TYPO3 server of the existing database

When I log in to the TYPO3 webpage, I have no templates configured and have a few issues. I tried to fix them by searching on internet but didn't find something clear.

- On the pages tab I only can see this:
  [image]
  in the log files:

[image]
The error is sending me to this page:
https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1294587217
I already did that, but didn't help, or I did it wrong

- On my templates tab there are "no templates":
  [image]

If someone can guide me to a next step, that would be very helpful.. thanks!

root template:

```
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.auth.user = bm
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.auth.password = sdfsdfdsf
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.url = https://sdfsdfdfs.com
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.https = 1
```

tree-view:

[image]

Web server root folder:
(laravel application is the green selected folder, with views,language files,..)

[image]

Comment: do you have the page tree displayed? Try to log on your install tool and remove all temp files and cache. If that wont work, if you have an ftp access, remove the content from the typo3temp.

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas I added it to the question.

Comment: where did you have your TypoScript on your old installtion? On an extension or in fileadmin?

Answer (score 0):

did you have all Extensions installed?

`typeNum=0 not configured` means you do not have created a PAGE Object within your TypoScript.

If you copy Data to a new TYPO3 installation, you need to install all Extension that are used in the source-installation. When the extensions are installed, they have to appear in the Template Module.

The `INVALID VALUE gridelements_pi1` is the same - it seems you didn't have installed Gridelements to the new TYPO3 Installation.

Install all dependencies and everything should work like expected.

EDIT:
Going a bit deeper - when installed all Extensions, then click on your rootpage (the globe) and then open the templates module. When there is still the `No Templates, you need to create one...` message, then create a new template for a `new page`.
After you created it, you can open the tab `Includes` and select your templates there.

Comment: Update: The root templates works. It gives 4 lines:

Comment: plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.auth.user = bm
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.auth.password = dfsdfdsfsdf
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.url = https://dsfdsfsd.com
plugin.tx_ahcontentapi.settings.https = 1

Comment: I added my webserver root folder tree in original question.

Answer (score 0):

An TYPO3 installation consists of multiple parts:

1. the TYPO3 source (this can be updated individually)
   `/typo3_src` (normaly a symlink to the TYPO3 sources)
2. the database (some tables could be truncated (caches))
3. extensions (all active extensions are needed)
   `/typo3conf/ext/*`
4. language files
   `/typo3conf/l10n'
5. original data files (in case you want to have images or other data, e.g. pdf)
   `/fileadmin/` or any other folders you may use with a file-storage record
6. processed files (images mostly are used resized, which are precaculated and stored for faster access)
   `/typo3temp/assets`, `/typo3temp/DATA`, `/uploads`, `/fileadmin/__processed__`, ...
7. cached data (some codes are concatenated, so only one file needs to be included instead of a lot of small files)
   `/typo3temp/var`, `/typo3temp/CACHE`

Not all parts are necessary for a copy of the installation, but it will help if you can copy all parts.
All caches can be rebuild and so there might be some differences like another domain it is highly recommended to delete caches.
Most processed data can be rebuild (as long as the original files are still present). But sometimes it is not recognized that a file needs to be processed again.

---

In your case I assume you missed to copy the extensions, especially the site extension so that you also miss the definition of your page object.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought I installed the extensions by copy the "contentapi" and "contentelements" in the ext folder? Other steps I need to do?

Comment: The language files, original data files and processed files are all on my Laravel project. I have my laravel project in the root of my server. I will post it in orginal question

Comment: in your screenshot of the page module there are messages about missing definition for content lements of type `gridelements_pi1`, so you miss the extension `gridelements`, your errorlog gives hints that a site_extension is missing, that could be any extension. my recommendation: copy all extensions from `typo3conf/ext/`. on the other hand: there could be a `composer.json` with the whole configuration in it, though all necessary extensions might get fetched automatically.